# Correct setup of associations between JPA entities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

From the properties seen below how would I set the association between the entities correctly?

If I make a new instance of the `Question`entity, do I need to make a new empty `ArrayList` and then add category instances that each has an `ArrayList` containing only that question instance in order to have the relationship properly made?

Or is it sufficient to only make a new `ArrayList` on the `Question` entity and add category instances to that?

**Question entity**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "question_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") })
private List<Category> categories;
```

**Category entity**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private List<Question> questions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always take care of both sides in the object model, as it would be when programming without JPA mapping.

Hibernate documentation explains it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-associations-usingbidir).